# Does simplification of a function's expression change the function itself?

Tags: calculus, functions

Let $f(x) = \frac{(x - 2)(x - 3)}{x - 2}$. At this point, $f(2)$ is undefined.

By simplifying the expression, we can get $f(x) = x - 3$. $f(2) = -1$

Are these two functions same? Their graph differs, since they produce different outputs given the same input. But here, they are both considered $f(x)$.

This has something to do with limits in calculus but I don't exactly know the reason. I ran into this question while understanding limits.

Comment: The first function is undefined at $x=2$ but near $2$, the function has a limiting value of 
$-1$. The two functions are different as they have different domains. They have identical graphs, but the first one has a hole at $x=2$

Comment: You cannot say that $f(x) = x - 3, f(2) = -1$ since $2$ is not in the domain of $f$.  What you can say is that $$f(x) = \frac{(x - 2)(x - 3)}{x - 2} = x - 3, x \neq 2$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function is given by a mapping **and** its domain.

In your question, the domains are not the same. The domain of the first function is $\mathbb R\setminus \{2\}$. The domain of the second one is $\mathbb R$.

What is true as you refer to calculus is that

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 2} f(x) = -1$$

hence you can extend $f$ by continuity at $2$.

Comment: It seems that the two functions are not the same. With that being said, is it correct for me to write f(x) = [(x - 2)(x - 3)]/(x - 2) = x - 3? The two ratios are the same, but they mean different functions.

Comment: The two functions are **equal** for $x\neq 2$. Again they are not the same **because their domains are different**. The first one is not defined at $x =2$.

Comment: @AhZong No, it's not correct for you to write that. It would be correct however to write "**For $x\not=2$ we have** $f(x)=x-3$."

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same function. We say that two functions $f$ and $g$ are equal if $f(x)=g(x)$ for every $x$. Since the expressions you wrote are not equal at $x=2$ (because one of them is undefined), they do not define the same function.

However, it is true that both functions have the same limit as $x$ approaches $2$.
This is because when we evaluate the limit of a function as $x$ approaches $2$, we never allow $x$ to actually take the value $2$. When $x$ is very close to $2$, the expression $x-2$ is very small but still nonzero, so the expression $\frac{(x-2)(x-3)}{(x-2)}$ is still well defined and equal to $x-3$.